# By what means does the King wage war?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> A King over all
>   The nations will fall
>   His garment of white
>   Its hem stained red
>   The darkness made light
>   For sinners he bled
>   In one hand a sword
>   The word of his power
>   In the other a symbol
>   Of Earth's final hour.
>
> I am he that liveth, and was dead; and, behold, I am alive for evermore, Amen; and have have the keys of hell and of death.
>
> Who shall not fear thee, O Lord, and glorify thy name? for thou only art holy: for all nations shall come and worship before thee; for thy judgments are made manifest.
>
> And the seven angels came out of the temple, having the seven plagues, clothed in pure and white linen, and having their breasts girded with golden girdles.
>
> By these three was the third part of men killed, by the fire, and by the smoke, and by the brimstone, which issued out of their mouths.
>
> Ye are my friends, if ye do whatsoever I command you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He shall break them with

> A ROD OF IRON

because

> the biblical verses quoted are Rev 1:18, Rev 15:4, Rev 15:6, Rev 9:18, John 15:14 and converting those numbers to letters via A1Z26 yields AR OD OF IR ON, a clear reference to Psalm 2 (taken at least by the librettist of Handel's *Messiah* as messianic).

The initial bit of verse in the puzzle, so far as I can see, is

> standard-issue Christian imagery (a lot of it, again, taken from the book of Revelation) with nothing puzzly embedded in it; I assume it's just there to give context to what king is being referred to.